# java super not working as expected

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

```
public  class Counter{
    private int value;


    public int getValue(){
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue (int value){
        this.value = value;
    }

    public  void increment() {

        /* */
    }

    public  void decrement() {
        /* */
    }
}


public class LoopingCounter extends Counter{

    private int limit;

    public LoopingCounter(int limit){
        this.limit = limit;
    }

    public void increment(){
        int value = super.getValue();
        if( value == limit){

            System.out.println("Value has reached the limit, cannot increment any further!");
            setValue(0);

        } else{
            value++;
            setValue(value);
        }
    }
    public void decrement(){
        int value = super.getValue();
        if(value == limit){
            System.out.println("Value has reached the limit, cannot decrement any further!");            
        } else{
            value--;
            setValue(value);
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        System.out.println("override");
        return 1000;
    }

}

public class CounterTest{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        LoopingCounter lc = new LoopingCounter(100);


        for(int i=0; i<150; i++){
            lc.increment();
            System.out.println(lc.getValue());
        }

    }
}
```

In this case, the LoopingCounter is supposed to trigger the `getValue` method in Counter class. But for some reason when I run it, it keeps using its own `getValue` method.

Please help me understand why I cannot call the parent method this way.

Apologies:

I now see my mistake. I apologize. I did not realize the lc.getValue() and was puzzled why the lc.increment failed to call the super.getValue() properly. Morale of story is get enough sleep before posting in SO. -_-"

Comment: Sth like this was already answered, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032847/can-java-call-parent-overridden-method-in-other-objects-but-not-subtype

Comment: `LoopingCounter` defines it's own `getValue()` method. If you weren't expecting it to be invoked, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Are we talking about the calls to `super.getValue()` not working in the `increment` and `decrement` methods, or the call to `lc.getValue()` not working in your `CounterTest` class? If it's the latter then it's "not working as expected" because you don't understand how it actually works.

Comment: What is not working in that code ? Everything is working as expected.

Comment: I think even if you were able to find a way to invoke super.getValue(),it will return nothing because super class field value has not been set a value to return.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is correct . If you want to call the `Counter` class `getValue()` , then you need to have `super.getValue()` somewhere inside the `LoopingCounter` class `getvalue()` method . `lc.getValue()` will always call `getValue()` method defined inside the `LoopingCounter` class as `lc` is an instance of `LoopingCounter` .

Answer (score 1):

Your parent method is call but as your inherited class also has getValue() method so it's called after executing parent class method. You should change your way to get value from base class.

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS 8.4.9 Overloading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.4.9) and [JLS 8.4.8.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.1).

> If you override parent method in you child class, and you run that method with child class instance then overridden method should be run.

So you are getting correct behavior in your program.

For calling parent overridden method with child instance you can use `super` [keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is `Object Oriented Programming`  call [Overriding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_overriding) if class B extends class A, class A have method `void foo()` and class B also provides implementation for `void  foo()` method this is called overriding and if you create object of class B and invoke method foo() method of child class will be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call any method through child class then it will always first call child class method and then it calls super class method.

If you want to call super class method first then you write `super.getValue()` inside `getValue()` method  of `LoopingCounter` class.