# Call a Parent Method In Java

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I want to Call the Parent Method in Java With A child Reference

```
Truck tv=new Vehicle();
```

Truck is the child class and Vehicle is a parent Class should i have to use type casting?

Comment: It's not possible from outside the subclass (and there are good reasons for it).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can java call parent overridden method in other objects but not subtype?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032847/can-java-call-parent-overridden-method-in-other-objects-but-not-subtype)

Comment: `Vehicle tv=new Vehicle();` is legal and `Vehicle tv=new Truck();` is legal. But what you've written isn't because a Vehicle isn't a Truck (even though a Truck is a vehicle)

Comment: Is the parent method overriden by the child?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a reference variable of base class pointing to the object instantiated of the derived class, better have a reference of base class pointing to its own class i.e,

```
    Truck tv = new Truck();
```

Thanks,
Balaji.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing will not compile since Truck is a sublass and you are instantiating a superclass.

You need to call Truck's constructor like this:

```
Truck tv=new Truck();
```

Using that, all methods that are present in Vehicle can be called on the Truck reference