# how to use the method of super class with same name?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I have two classes, `Person` and `Student`, where `Student extends Person` and both classes have the `get` method.

I made an object from `Student` and I want to call both get with this object. how can I super the method of the superclass? Or is there any other way for doing that?

Comment: do you know what overriding mean?

Comment: You can't : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032847/can-java-call-parent-overridden-method-in-other-objects-but-not-subtype

Comment: Understand method overriding concept!

Comment: please show code example, I doubt what you want to do is possible in Java, it might be doable in C# with `new` and method hiding

Answer (score 0):

`super` codeword in java serves as a reference to the super class.
So, for example we have a `get()` method in `Person` class and another in `Student` class  which extends `Person` .
To call `get()` method of `Person` inside `Student` we can just use `super.get()`.