# define common variables across multiple classes using interfaces

Tags: java, interface

I have a sample interface

```
 public interface SampleVariables {
int var1=0;
int var2=0;
}
```

and I want to use var1 and var2 across multiple classes i am trying to do this using

```
public class InterfaceImplementor  extends Message  implements SampleVariables{

private int var3;

public int getVar1(){
    return var1;
}

public void setVar1(int var1){
    SampleVariables.var1=var1; // ** error here in eclipse which says " remove final modifier of 'var1' " Though I have not defined it as final
}

public int getVar3() {
    return var3;
}

public void setVar3(int var3) {
    this.var3 = var3;
}

}
```

where class Message is a pre-defined class which I try to use and I cannot define var1, var2 in the class Message.

Is there a better way to do this? Or am I missing something really simple ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All fields in an interface are *implicitly* static and final, hence your warning above. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513520/java-why-all-fields-in-an-interface-are-implicitly-static-and-final) for more details.

It seems to me that you want a base class with these variables, but as you've noted you can't do this since you're deriving from a 3rd party class.

I would not derive from that 3rd-party class, since you don't control its implementation. I would rather create a class that *wraps* it and provides your additional functionality. That gives you a level of comfort that if/when that 3rd-party class changes, you can limit the scope of the changes that you have to subsequently make.

Unfortunately Java doesn't support [mixins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin), which is what you're trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

In `interface` by default **variables** are `static final` you cannot change there value ie. you cannot do `SampleVariables.var1=var1;`

what you can do is

```
public class InterfaceImplementor  extends Message { // do not implement interface here

private int var3;
private int var1;

public void setVar1(int var1){
    this.var1=var1; // will work
}
```

and to access variable of `interface` `SampleVariables.var1`

Answer (score 1):

Since member variable of Interface are by `default static, final` so you can't `reassign` the value again once you have initialized.

`Every field declaration in the body of an interface is implicitly public, static, and final. It is permitted to redundantly specify any or all of these modifiers for such fields.`

See [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.3).

Answer (score 0):

You should use an abstract class for this.

example:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass {
    protected int var1;
}
class SubClass1 extends AbstractClass {

}
class SubClass2 extends AbstractClass {

}
```

This way SubClass1 and SubClass2 will have a var1. Note that you can do the same with getters and setters, but for making the point this was shorter.