# Solution to extend multiple classes

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, extends

Let's say I have Class A and B that differ except on using color variables.
Both classes already extend the JPanel Class so I cannot extend a new class with the color variables in it. I then thought I could make class C (with the colors in it) an interface. But it's not allowed to have attributes in an interface.

Any idea how I can still use the colors in an external class for both Class A + B?

The thought:

Class A - Uses the colors
Class B - Uses the colors
Class C - Has the colors.

Comment: define the colors in C and make a getColor method in c which returns the colors

Comment: You can have a class `Z` that extends from `JPanel` and only adds a `C cHasTheColors` field, then classes `A` and `B` can extend from `Z` having all the power of `JPanel` and the `C` field in them (of course, if this is want you wanted to have).

Comment: What if you make the classes A and B generic? At runtime, you pass them the color you want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use an interface for storing constants.

```
public interface C{
    Color a;
    Color b; 
    //And so on
}
```

Now have A and B implement this class, and that should do it.

Comment: Are you sure that is allowed? Please tell me if I am wrong but I was told you can only use unimplemented methods in an interface.

Comment: Well, those are `public static final` variables, not methods. I suppose that's what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface C {
  public static final Color c1 = Color.RED;
  public static final Color c2 = Color.GREEN;
  public static final Color c3 = Color.BLUE;
}

public class A extends JPanel implements C {
    /* ... */
}

public class B extends JPanel implements C {
    /* ... */
}
```

EDIT: As noted in Luiggi Mendoza's comment, your `Color`s would [have to be static and final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513520/java-why-all-fields-in-an-interface-are-implicitly-static-and-final).

Comment: Note that fields in an interface would be marked as `static final` thus not being *shared* among the instances of the classes that implement the interface.

Comment: So it's allowed to have static final variables in an interface? :D