# How to call grandparent constructor with parameters in Java?

Tags: java, constructor, super

Maybe the question have many people ask, but I still don't know how to get the answer.

I have A, B, C class.

C extends B, B extends A.

the main method in the C class.

If I want to call A constructor method with parameters in C class,

how can I do?

thanks you very much.

**A class**

```
 public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println("A construtor");
    }

    public A(int a, int b)
    {
        System.out.println("A.a:"+ a + "/B.b:"+b);
    }
 }
```

**B class**

```
 public class B extends A{
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B construtor");
    }

    public B(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("B.a:" + a + "/B.b:" + b);
    }
 }
```

**C class**

```
 public class C extends B{

    public static void main(String[] str)
    {
        C c = new C();
    }

    public C() {
 //     super(1,2);
        // how to call A constructor with parameters 
        System.out.println("C constructor");

    }

 }
```

Comment: Can calling like this be avoided or is it absolutely necessary? It can get very messy very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Class C does not explicitly extend class A, it is only via class B that C extends A, hence you will only be able to access the constructors of A, via the constructors of Class B.

By using super(1,2) in Class C's constructor you will call Class B's constructor which has two int parameters. You would need to change class B's arg constructor to the following:

```
public class B extends A{
public B() {
    System.out.println("B construtor");
}

public B(int a, int b) {
super(a,b);
    System.out.println("B.a:" + a + "/B.b:" + b);
}
```

}

Bear in mind the following:

1)When no constructor is supplied to a class, java creates a default non-arg constructor.

2)If a class A extends class B, class B requires a constructor and the superclasses must be called at first.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you can, directly from C. It would need to be done by calling the appropriate B constructor within C's constructor. e.g.,

**A class**

```
 public class A {

    public A() {
        System.out.println("A construtor");
    }

    public A(int a, int b)
    {
        System.out.println("A.a:"+ a + "/B.b:"+b);
    }
 }
```

**B class**

```
 public class B extends A{
    public B() {
        System.out.println("B construtor");
    }

    public B(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println("B.a:" + a + "/B.b:" + b);
    }

    // ****** added ******
    public B(int a, int b, boolean ignore) {
        super(a, b);
    }
 }
```

**C class**

```
 public class C extends B{

    public static void main(String[] str)
    {
        C c = new C();
    }

    public C() {
        super(1, 2, true);
        System.out.println("C constructor");

    }

 }
```

Curious -- can you give a solid reason for why you'd want to do this?

Comment: If I add public void callAConstructor()
 {
  super(1,2);
 } in class B. It will show "Constructor can must be the first statement in a constructor"

Comment: @dickfala: and that is correct: a super constructor call **always** must be done first. Please see edit to answer.

Comment: I just study java . I just think the problem. So I don't know if we encounter the problem, how to do . thanks.

Comment: @dickfala: note that [this has been asked many times before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878558/jump-over-parent-constructor-to-call-grandparents). I have changed my answer to a community wiki because of this.