# Call 'grand' parent function from child class in multi-level inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

```
public class GrandParent
{
    public void walk()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public void walk()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public void walk()
    {
        // Here in some cases I want to use walk method of GrandParent class
    }
}
```

Now in Child.walk(), I want to use GrandParent.walk() only in some cases. How can I do that? Since super.walk() will always use Parent.walk().

**NOTE:** (Please note that this is simplified example of a complex scenario)

**NOTE2:** Please only tell if there is a standard procedure of doing that. I have used a flag in parent class, which the child sets if it wants to use the method of GrandParent. But this sequence becomes very complex.

Comment: Put the same logic you use in `Child` into `Parent`, too.

Comment: Can't you just cast the child instance to the grandparent type and call walk on that?

Comment: Just as a side note, you may be interested in knowing that you are breaking encapsulation by trying to access GrandParent functionality from Child. Merely a "good design" point, but I felt that it was relevant. For more, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Comment: @0xCAFEBABE The most specific implementation of the method is called. By casting the child to grandparent won't change the availability of the most specific implementation.

Comment: The terminology confuses me a bit, am used to hearing `walk` and `parent` used together when describing object trees, not class inheritance.

Comment: Seems like you have a design problem. You are not suppose to do that. It would be helpful to give us some background: Why you need to do this??

Comment: Is it possible to make `walk` function parametrise

Comment: @Real yep it is possible but that's not much different from creating a flag in parent classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could specify method for accessing parent's value like this:

```
public class GrandParent
{
    public void walk()
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class Parent
{
    public void walk()
    {
        ...
    }

    public void grandParentWalk()
    {
        super.walk();
    }
}

public class Child
{
    public void walk()
    {
        grandParentWalk();
    }
}
```

### Similar questions:

- [Java: How do you access a parent class method two levels down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118067/java-how-do-you-access-a-parent-class-method-two-levels-down)
- [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java?lq=1)

Comment: Again, For a lot of such methods, things will become complex.

Comment: You could not break OOP principles without breaking eggs.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here is in the decision to call the Parent function "walk". It should not have been called "walk" unless it is intended to be a complete functional replacement for the GrandParent `walk()`.

If that decision cannot be changed, then the solution suggested in the existing answer from @zvzdhk is the best that can be done.

Ideally, the Parent `walk()` would be given a new name reflecting whatever is different about its function from the GrandParent `walk()`. Each of the functions could then be called from the Child class.