# How do I access a superclass method in java if it has already been overridden by a subclass?

Tags: java, polymorphism, overriding

Assuming I have the abstract Shape class, within I have the method `getArea()`. As a subclass of the Shape class, I have the Rectangle class, which overrides the `getArea()` method. As a subclass of the Rectangle class, I have the Square class, but in the Square class, I want to reference the `getArea()` as implemented in the Shape class. How can I do this without copying the code over?

Comment: You can access the immediate superclass' method with `super.getArea()`, but you can't jump in the hierarchy at will. That indicates design problems.

Comment: You just override the getArea() method. I do not believe that you can get to the getArea() of a "grandparent" object. I think if you want to, then you might be having an incorrect class hierarchy. I would probably have Square be a special case of Rectangle rather than a child of it.

Comment: Polymorphism doesn't allbow this. This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118067/java-how-do-you-access-a-parent-class-method-two-levels-down) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java How to call method of grand parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents)