# Specify which superclass to call a method from

Tags: java, inheritance

I have a hierarchy with several levels, it looks something like this (<---- denotes subclassing of left from right):

```
MyClass <----- ParentClass <------ Abstract Class
```

I want to call a non-static method that is declared and defined in AbstractClass, but is overridden in ParentClass. I want to call the version in AbstractClass, not the version in ParentClass, so I need something like

```
super.super.method();
```

Or something of that spirit. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: NO super.super available in Java.

Comment: I'm aware that syntax doesn't work. But is there a way to do what I'm asking?

Comment: It sounds like that method shouldn't be overriden.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java How to call method of grand parents?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents)

Comment: It's a library design decision I unfortunately do not have control over.

Comment: If you are aware of the syntax I think it is time to re-consider design.

Comment: Thanks for the point scrappedcola. I tried to find such things but didn't think to search "grandparent"...

Answer (score 2):

[This Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java) has a good discussion of this issue. In short, there a couple of hacky ways to do it, but [you really shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/1437878).