# Java grandchild object not allowed to call parent's or grandparent's methods

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have have a class `A` in Java and `A` has some protected methods, I then have a class `B` which `extends` from `A` so that `B` can override those protected methods. I then want the ability to have a class `C` that `extends` from class `B` but class `C` should not be able to call `A`'s protected methods. Is there away to do that in Java? Do I just make the parent's class's method's overriden and have them final? i.g.

```
public class A()
{
     protected void somemethod();
     protected int somevariable;
}

public class B() extends A
{
    @Override
    final protected void somemethod();
        //How do I make some variable final or not accessible to my children?
    }

    public class C() extends B
    {
        //Now I cannot override somemethod! Is that right?
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you have got it right. And why don't you simply try it? And you should not have brackets following the class names.

Comment: Why the hell is there a () beside the class name? Is that valid (And I'm too lazy to try it :D)?

Comment: I believe it is not possible to override a method and suddenly make it `final`. That would be an illegal override, because in the eyes of the compiler it is not the same method, but it too can't distinguish from a method call which method to call. Thus: invalid. (I'm not entirely sure about that, need to check it.)

Comment: @LewsTherin, yeah sorry about that... that isn't my actual code and eclipse generates class definitions for me, so I don't have the code for class headers down... I think I need to start programming in a text editor more often so I don't get too lazy :)

Comment: @11684 No this is false, you may override a method and make it final. This can be useful when defining a method in an interface, then you provide a `final` implementation in an abstract class so that the exact same behavior is available in all subclasses. This `final` method might call what we cann `hooks` to allow customization of the method.

Comment: Ah, I'll reread my (perhaps slightly outdated) book on Java. Thanks! @Laf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot prevent a child class from calling a parent's `protected` methods. To achieve this, you would have to reduce the method's visibility, which is not allowed. Making the method `final` in your class `B` only means it cannot be overriden in any subclasses.

The fact that you want disallow calls to `protected` methods for child classes appears to be a design problem to me. You might want to review how your whole class hierarchy and maybe better isolate the reponsibilites of your classes so that you don't get into a situation where you have to prevent what would normally be allowed (calling `protected` methods).

Answer (score 1):

```
//How do I make some variable final or not accessible to my children?
```

For this you can make a variable **private** and **final**:

```
private final int COUNT = 100;
```

**private accessor** will prevent your variable COUNT to be accessed by child classes.

Comment: Nope, in that case class B wouldn't be able to override A's method.

Comment: @11684: I think OP's question is about a variable only.

Comment: Reading the comments in the code snippet I certainly got the impression it was about a method. As I read it, the question is: `Can I make an overridden method unoverridable for classes extending the overrider`.

Comment: My bad on the question... as I was writing it I was thinking "Oh no! What about a variable...?"

Answer (score 1):

It is enough if B overrides the protected methods to prevent C from accessing the methods as implemented in A. C will then only have accesss to the methods as implemented in B . Have a look at [Java How to call method of grand parents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2584377/java-how-to-call-method-of-grand-parents) .