# How is the code flows in method overriding

Tags: java, overriding

For the below code I got the output as

```
In Base.foo()  
In Derived.bar()
```

Code:

```
class Base {
    public static void foo(Base bObj) {
        System.out.println("In Base.foo()");
        bObj.bar();
    }  
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("In Base.bar()");
    }
}
class Derived extends Base {
    public static void foo(Base bObj) {
        System.out.println("In Derived.foo()");
        bObj.bar();
    }
    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("In Derived.bar()");
    }
}
class OverrideTest {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        Base bObj = new Derived();
        bObj.foo(bObj);
    }
}
```

How the code flows? How I am getting the output as the above. I confused little bit and looking for the explanation.

Comment: Static methods are not overriden.

Comment: What did you expect, and why? It's a lot easier to explain where your thinking is mistaken if you explain what that thinking is first. Note that you're calling a static method via a variable, which is a really bad idea to start with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overriding static methods in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617408/overriding-static-methods-in-java)

Comment: @JonSkeet Not even sure why that is allowed in Java.  It only generates confusion.  To his credit, he probably doesn't realize how to properly call a static method.

Comment: @Neil: Basically, it's a design flaw in Java, IMO.

Comment: Well i think the author of the topic just tried out one of these exercises in preparation for java professional certification. Therefore the use of the static method from the variable it may be confusing on purpose.

Comment: It's allowed @Neil because it's static, you can statically call it on either class.  It's completely different.

Comment: @JonSkeet why do you posit the fact that class-scoped methods are bound to compile time and not overridden is a design flaw in Java? Isn't that the same for C# by the way?

Comment: @RossDrew I know it's static.  It doesn't require an instance to launch, although you *can* use one.  I just fail to see how the usefulness of this overshadows the confusion created by this.

Comment: @Mena: Because it causes confusion - I've seen it in many, many cases, e.g. where someone calls `someThread.sleep(...)` and expects it to put that thread to sleep, rather than the *current* thread. And no, it's not the same in C# - you can't call a static method via an expression in C#. You'd have to call `Thread.Sleep` instead of `someThread.Sleep`. (And let's call them "static" methods instead of "class-scoped"... scope in the normal meaning of the word is somewhat orthogonal to this.)

Comment: Because it's attached specifically to the class.  If you had a static `create()` factory like method, you could have it on `Base` and `Derived` and expect to call it specifically on each class and expect different behavior.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think I understand your point now. The design flow would be being able to invoke a `static` method on an instance object - I thought you were challenging the fact `static` methods are not overridden :)

Comment: @RossDrew And when I see things like baseClass.create() and the Derived class create() gets called instead, it makes me want to scream.  If you interpret one behavior in the code you read and it does another, it should be avoided for clear and concise code.  I don't want to have to check if create() is a static method to know which is being called.

Answer (score 3):

Static methods are not overridden, there's no virtual invocation.

In your `Derived` class, the `static foo` method is *hiding* its parent class' `static foo` method.

However, in your `main` method, you are invoking `foo` on a reference type `Base`, hence `Base#foo` gets invoked (so it prints `"In Base.foo()"`).

In turn, the static method invokes `bar` on the passed object, which **IS-A** `Base`, but happens to be an instance of `Derived`.

Since `bar` is an instance method and **is** overridden given your signature matches, the invocation resolves to the instance type, which is `Derived`, hence `"In Derived.bar()"` is printed.

**Notes**

- A good practice is to employ the `@Override` annotation on overridden methods. 
  This would fail to compile for your `foo` method as it's static, thus clearly pointing out there's no possible overriding there.
- Another good practice (as pointed out by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)) is to avoid invoking `static` methods on instance objects (i.e. prefer an explicit `ClassName.staticMethod` idiom), as this may cause confusion on the scope in which the method is invoked.

Comment: I'd add that it's also good practice not to call static methods like this, but instead specify the class name.

Answer (score 0):

Code flow will be like

Base bObj = new Derived();

Here you are creating the bObj with type Base and the runtime object will be of class Derived.

bObj.foo(bObj);

as foo() is a static method and static binding happened at compile time so it will not check for the runtime object type.So as you are declaring a Base type object ,the method in Base will get executed.Inside that function you are calling non static methos bar() with the object argument.The object passed at runtime is your Derived class instance ,hence it will be called.