# Calling Object implementation of hashCode

Tags: java, hashcode

I have a hierarchy like this:

```
public class A {
    public abstract int hashCode();
}
public class B extends A {
    public int hashCode(){
        //I want this to return the object implementation of hash code
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I want b.hashCode() to return the Object implementation of hashCode().  Unfortunately B has to extend A, and A can't change.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just return [`System.identityHashCode(this)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29).

Comment: Cool, thanks, that works.  Except I can't accept this answer for 15 minutes.

Comment: Nifty. I was going to suggest some ugly workaround, but of course, if there's already something that does it...

Comment: In addition to the `System.identityHashCode(this);`, also refer to the accepted answer in regards to "super super class" invocations (if you were thinking of doing this with a different method as well):

[super super class method invocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456177/calling-super-super-class-method)