# Calling super class method

Tags: java, android

I have class A which has a method `sum()`.

Now class `B` extends class `A` and overrides `sum()` method, and

class `C` extends class `B` and also overrides `sum()` method.

Now I create an instance of class `C`.

My question is: How can I call class `A`'s `sum()` method in class `C` through `C` instance? One of the way is call `super.sum()` in `B` and `C`. Is there any other way?

Comment: A obj = new C(); then call method obj.sum(); Or use super to call that  method

Comment: No, as per accepted answer of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3456177/calling-super-super-class-method

Comment: Where you have created an instance of class C ?

Comment: @Sudz in main method of Main class

Comment: First you will have to call that method from the class `B` using `super.sum()` and create another method in your class `B` and from that method class `B` method call the super class `A` method and in your class `C` you call the class `B` method by creating instance of class `C`. This way it will first call first the class `B` method in which there is already called first class `A` method. This way it can work.

Comment: @GrIsHu can you represent your answer programmatically?

Comment: @RuntimeException You can refer the answer of "Seelenvirtuose" for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no syntactical way of calling the method A.sum() inside any method of C. You need to place a *bridging* method inside B for doing that:

```
public class A {
    public void sum() { System.out.println("A.sum()"); }
}

public class B extends A {
    @Override
    public void sum() { System.out.println("B.sum()"); }
    protected final void superSum() { super.sum(); }
}

public class C extends B {
    @Override
    public void sum() { System.out.println("C.sum()"); }
    public void someMethod() {
        sum();
        super.sum();
        superSum();
    }
}
```

Calling C.someMethd() prints out

```
C.sum()
B.sum()
A.sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside B's & C's  sum method place super() so that it will call A's sum method.

```
B extends A{
sum(){
super();
//dosomething..
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can call A's sum in B using super.sum() but i don't think u can do that from C.

The best way would be to call super.sum() in both B's anc C's sum

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this :

```
class A{
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("a");
    }
}
class B extends A {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("b");
    }
    public void callmethod(){
        super.method();
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public void method() {
        System.out.println("c");
    }
    public void callmethod(){
        super.callmethod();
    }
}
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c = new C();
    c.callmethod();
}
```

}