# ambiguity in invoking a method inherited from another class

Tags: java

I have two java class files

Hi.java which belongs to second package

```
package second;

public class Hi {
protected int v=20;
protected void m(){
    System.out.println("i am protectTED");
}
}
```

S.java which belong to first package

```
 package first;
import second.Hi;
interface i1
{
void m();
int a=200;
}
interface i2{
void m1();
int b=100;
}
class S extends Hi implements i1,i2
{
int a=50;
public void m()
{
    System.out.println("hi");
}
public void m1()
{
    System.out.println("hello");
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    S s=new S();

    /*need correction here (i don't know the exact syntax to mention to get 
    the desired output)
    s.m(); //should invoke method m() from class Hi only.
    s.m(); //Should invoke method m() from class S only.
    */

    //the following statements prints the desired values

    s.m1();
    System.out.println(s.v);
    System.out.println(i1.a);
    System.out.println(s.a);
    System.out.println(b);

}
}
```

when i run the S.java class file method m() in class Hi should be invoked.("my intention") instead method m() of the same class i.e., class S is being invoked.

How to differentiate the 2 methods for invoking. Is it even possible?

Comment: That's the way method overriding behaves in Java. In order to "differentiate" the methods, they'll need to have different signatures.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22343982/calling-super-class-method ?

Answer (score 1):

> when i run the S.java class file method m() in class Hi should be invoked.("my intention") instead method m() of the same class i.e., class S is being invoked.

Correct, because you've overridden it with `m` in `S`. Overriding methods is fundamentally different from overriding fields. (And in general, it's best to avoid overriding any fields that are visible to your subclass, as you're doing with `a`.)

In *instance* code in `S`, you can run the inherited `m` via `super`: `super.m()`. But you cannot do that from static code, not even static code in `S`. You could give yourself a private `callSuperM` in `S`:

```
private void callSuperM() {
    super.m();
}
```

...and then use that in `main`:

```
s.callSuperM(); // "i am protectTED"
s.m();          // "hi"
```