# selenium: override setUp method in super class and call super super method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have a setUp() in my SuperTest class. Now in my ChildTest class, I want to set up another setUp(). This one will run specifically for ChildTest only.

So I currently have this

```
    //SuperClass
    protected void setUp(ITestContext context) {
        ...
    }

    //SubClass extends SuperClass
    @BeforeMethod
    protected void setUp(ITestContext context) {
        super.setUp(context);
        ...
    }

    //ChildClass extends SubClass
    @Override
    @BeforeMethod
    protected void setUp(ITestContext context) {
        super.setUp(context);
        ...
    }
```

The problem is, when I run ChildTest, it runs both of the setUp() from SubClass and it's own... How can I get it so it'll only run it's own setUp()?

Comment: @olyv yes I do (forgot to include the tag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3456599

I ended up adding a method in the SubClass that calls the setUp of SuperClass

```
    //SubClass extends SuperClass
    protected void getSuperSuper((ITestContext context) {
        super.setUp(context);
    }

    //ChildClass extends SubClass
    protected void setUp(ITestContext context) {
        super.getSuperSuper(context);
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No it should not run both the setup methods, if you have extended the parent class and followed all the rules of [overriding](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm) a method then there in no way your parent class method is going to get executed. Consider the following scenario. I have two TestNG classes with Abc as the parent class and Def as the child class

```
public class Abc{

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("PARENT");
}
```

}

```
public class Def extends Abc{

@BeforeMethod
public void beforeMethod(ITestContext context) {
    System.out.println("CHILD");
}

@Test
public void test(){
    System.out.println("TEST");
}
```

}

Now if I execute the Def class as TestNg Test, it is definitely going to execute beforeMethod of the child class and then after that the test method of the child class

Comment: But it does run both. I had to comment out the super class setUp for the child class to run it's own setUp. I also did what you did and print out on console, it clearly shows "super" and "child"

Comment: I am not able to figure out what are you missing upon but when I execute the above scenario it prints:  CHILD and then TEST