# Java and skipping a level with super

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

If you have a class that derives from a class that derives from another is there anyway for me to call the super.super method and not the overridden one?

```
class A{
    public void some(){}
} 

class B extends A{
    public void some(){}
} 

class C extends B{
    public void some(){I want to call A.some();}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

See: [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Answer (score 3):

@tgamblin is right but here is a workaround :

```
class A{
    public void some(){ sharedCode() }
    public final void someFromSuper(){ sharedCode() }

    private void sharedCode() { //code in A.some() }
} 

class B extends A{
    @Override
    public void some(){}
} 

class C extends B{
    @Override
    public void some(){
     //I want to call A.some();
     someFromSuper();
    }
}
```

Create a second version of your method in A that is final (not overridable) and call it from C.

This is actually a poor design, but sometimes needed and used inside JDK itself.

Regards, 
 Stéphane