# Skip class implementation in inheritance tree

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

I have the following class structure:

```
Class Human, with message("Hello, ")
Class Townsmen extends Human, with message("I live in town.")
Class Merchant extends Townsmen, with message("I'm merchant.")
```

Is it possible for an instance of Merchant to say "Hello, I'm merchant.", using `super` calls? I have a program in Java, and the code is much more complex, but the idea is the same. In addition I cannot modify Human nor Townsmen classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible in Java, which doesn't allow multiple inheritance. The correct way to do this would be:

```
      Human
     /     
  TownMember
  /       \
 Townsmen  Merchant
```

With TownMember having whatever logic that townsmen has that merchant inherits.

Since you can't do that, you're going to need to have Merchant extend Human and just re-implement that logic.

Comment: Multiple inheritance isn't really the issue here. Skipping intermediate superclass implementations however, is.

Answer (score 3):

All I can think of is:
`Class Merchant extends Human, with message("I'm merchant.")`

I don't think you can skip the superclass constructors you don't like - this isn't how inheritance works.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can hack around using reflection to get what you want (see [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)). However, DONT!

The problem you are facing is solvable using the right design.

As a thumb rule - If you are trying to achieve something very unique that the language itself tries to restrict, probably something is wrong with your design. (my 2 cents ;))

Answer (score 0):

You can have Merchant not call a super method and do what ever the Human.message does. It can use reflections if permissions is a problem.

However it appears that a Merchant is not a Townsman and should extend Human.