# Select certain super class for method call in Scala

Tags: scala

If I have a class constellation in Scala like this:

```
class A {
def foo() = "bar"
}

class B extends A {
override def foo() = "BAR"
}

class C extends B {
}
```

is it possible in class C to explicitly call the method foo that was defined in A?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can't, because it violates encapsulation. You are bypassing your parents behaviour, so  C is supposed to extend B, but you are bypassing this.

Please see Jon Skeets excellent answer to the same question [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java).

Please note that you can access the field by reflection, but you don't want to do that.

Answer (score 18):

No, but you can do something similar with multiple trait inheritance:

```
trait A { def foo = "from A" }

class B extends A { override def foo = "from B" }

class C extends B with A {
  val b = foo          // "from B"
  val a = super[A].foo // "from A"
}
```

Comment: And why this does not violate encapsulation as @Matthew said in his answer?

Comment: In this example, class `C` explicitly extends `A`, so it gets direct access `A`'s behavior. To be honest, this example looks odd, and I'm not sure it's good style.

Answer (score 2):

No. And I would leave it at that, but apparently SO wants me to go on for 30 characters.

Comment: If you happen to know the reason why this is not possible, that could be something to fill up the 30 Characters :)