# Accessing a method in a super super class

Tags: scala, superclass, super

I want to invoke a method on the parent of a parent class. I am almost certain this is possible, but the following produces an error:

```
import javax.swing.undo._

def test(name: String): CompoundEdit = new CompoundEdit {
  override def getPresentationName    : String = name

  override def getUndoPresentationName: String = 
    super[AbstractUndoableEdit].getUndoPresentationName

  override def getRedoPresentationName: String = 
    super[AbstractUndoableEdit].getRedoPresentationName
}
```

The compiler says `AbstractUndoableEdit` is not a parent class of `CompoundEdit` (which is [wrong](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/CompoundEdit.html)):

```
<console>:55: error: AbstractUndoableEdit does not name a parent class of <$anon: javax.swing.undo.CompoundEdit>
         override def getUndoPresentationName: String = super[AbstractUndoableEdit].getUndoPresentationName
                                                        ^
<console>:56: error: AbstractUndoableEdit does not name a parent class of <$anon: javax.swing.undo.CompoundEdit>
         override def getRedoPresentationName: String = super[AbstractUndoableEdit].getRedoPresentationName
                                                        ^
```

Comment: Actually I think it is not possible. See the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028627/select-certain-super-class-for-method-call-in-scala

Comment: @lpiepiora thanks for the link; that's unfortunate; can you post that as an answer, anyways

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. The reason for that is, that it would violate encapsulation.

See [why is super.super not allowed in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java) and [similar question for scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028627/select-certain-super-class-for-method-call-in-scala)