# Java: accessing grandparent's state

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, superclass

I know in Java, especially when you do field hiding, you are able to access grandparent's state variables:

```
((Grandparent) this).hiddenField
```

Why is the same rationale not the case for method calls? you can call super.method(), why not other ancestor's as well?

Comment: uhm ... have you tried this.Grandparent.method() ?

Comment: Grandparent is a class name, it is not an instance field...

Comment: I think you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no analog of field hiding for instance methods. Instance methods, unlike instance fields or **static** methods, are subject to dynamic dispatch and that's a whole different story. In a sense, an overridden method is just not "there" anymore, and the only exception is within the overriding method body, and there only the method being directly overridden.

Answer (score 1):

Because methods are virtual, and fields are not.
The goal was to call the same method regardless of the type of reference:

`(Grandparent) this).method()` always equals `this.method()`.