# Calling super on a grandparent class?

Tags: java, super

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

```
Class A
Class B extends A
Class C extends B
```

How can I make a method in class C call the super of class A?

I tried this but it fails...

```
A.super.someMethod();
```

Comment: `C extends A` - did you mean `C extends B`? (as the title suggests)

Answer (score 2):

If you meant to call `super.super.someMethod()` in Java then simple answer is that you cannot do that. Java intentionally prohibits that because it violates encapsulation.