# Java children execute method of ancestor

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

There are three classes - `Children`, `Father`, and `Ancestor`. `Children` extends `Father`, and `Father` extends `Ancestor`, like below:

```
public class Ancestor {
    public void test() {
    }
}

public class Father extends Ancestor {
    @Override
    public void test() {
    }
}

public class Children extends Father {
    @Override
    public void test() {
    }
}
```

How I can use Ancestor's test() method in Children's test() method? I want to skip Father's test() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Java does not permit doing something like `super.super.method()`. The reasons for this are outlined in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/465378), but the bottom line is that it violates encapsulation.

If the functionality is really necessary, and it makes sense to do something like this, you can always add a method in your `Father` class that just calls the `super.test()` method, but doing things like this is usually bad practice. Unless you have some *really* good reasoning, rethink your code. There shouldn't really be any necessity to call a method from either `this` nor `super`.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is, you can't.  It violates encapsulation and is generally bad practice.  A better way to accomplish what you want would be to make Ancestor.test() abstract and have a new protected method like Ancestor.baseTest();  Then, you could call Ancestor.baseTest() from Father, Child and any other subclass that wants to access the logic.

Comment: My only problem with this is that it really *shouldn't* be necessary in most cases. By proposing that such a solution is a perfectly valid one, you may leave the false impression that this is an okay thing to do. Really, you should stay away from things like this.

Comment: I agree it shouldn't be necessary in most cases.  However, the question didn't give enough context to make a recommendation. If it really is necessary, its better to give the option, IMHO.

Comment: I guess that's true, but while my answer *did* give the option, it also precautioned against using such methods unless absolutely necessary. Just saying.