# Java: How to call super().super() in overridden method (grandparent method)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

I have 3 classes they inherit from each other as follows:

```
A
 ↳
   B
    ↳
     C
```

Inside each class I have the following method:

```
protected void foo() {
    ...
}
```

Inside class `C` I want to call `foo` from class `A` without calling `foo` in `B`:

```
protected void foo() {
    // This doesn't work, I get the following compile time error:
    // Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor
    super().super().foo(); 
}
```

**EDIT**
Some Context Info:
Class B is an actual class we use. Class C is a unit test class, it has some modifications. `foo` method inside `B` does some things we don't want so we override it inside `C`. However `foo` in class `A` is useful and needs to be called.

Comment: Take a look at this topic  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Answer (score 23):

- To call a method in a super class, you use `super.foo()`, not `super().foo()`. `super()` calls the constructor of the parent class.
- There is no way to call `super.super.foo()`. You can add a call to `super.foo()` in class B, so that calling `super.foo()` in C, will call `super.foo()` in B which in turn will call `foo()` in A.

Answer (score 15):

It's not possible in Java. You'd need to rely on `B` providing you with an explicit way to access to `A`'s `foo`.