# How to Call the super class's super method

Tags: java

```
class a
{
void show()
{
}
class b extends a
{
void show()
{
}
class c extends b
{
//how to call show method of class a
}
}

}
```

Does anyone know how I can call method of class a from class c using super keyword

Comment: Please format that code. Also, what language are you using? Assuming pseudocode, I would say that "show()" should be inherited to class "C", so it should be callable anyway. Assuming that "show()" in class "A" is private, it depends on the language - assuming C#, there would be no way to call it from class "A" (since the method is private).

Comment: Seems duplicate:  https://stackoverflow.com/q/11935895/11226492 https://stackoverflow.com/q/586363/11226492

Answer (score 1):

```
class A {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

class B extends A {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }
}

class C extends B {
    void show() {
        super.show();
    }
}
```

The above code will display "B" when class C object is invoked.
In your case, there can be 2 options:

1. C extends A - This will let super.show() in show method of class C display "A".
2. Add super.show() in show method of class B so that show method of class C displays both "B" and "A".

There is no way to call super class methods which are higher than level 1.