# How to skip one level in inheritance calling super from grandparent in java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, constructor, superclass

I have simple three classes:

```
class A {
  public A(int a){ }
}

class B extends A {
  public B(int b){ super(b); }
}

class C extends B {
  public C(int c){ super(c); }
}
```

So, the order of execution during class instancing is C->B->A->B->C and all objects are instantiated correctly. Then, the question:

CAN I in some way write a constructor for C class like this:

```
  public C(int c){
    super.super(c);
  }
```

The idea is to call the constructor from A class, not from immediate parent B. Is this possible?

Comment: Well, there are no methods being overridden here, so just call `A(c)`. (I'm assuming this is a typo though - please fix your code to actually illustrate your problem).

Comment: The code won't even compile at the moment, because you're not declaring constructors - you're declaring methods with names the same as the classes.

Comment: A is meant to be the constructor, I guess. OP maybe should think about his architecture, though.

Comment: possible duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11935895/java-how-to-call-super-super-in-overriden-method-grandparent-method) and [another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Comment: Inheritance is unconditional, so do not extend if you don't actually want the "B" part every time. Make a class that extends directly from A, and in case it should have something in common with the others that isn't inherited directly put that into a common `interface`. Not being able to skip a class is not a limitation, it's a design issue on your side.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I redesigned the code and constructors are OK and I have no more problems with them. However, I have a very similar issue in this simple class hierarchy: in class A, B, and C I have a "makeStr" function, which is creating some string. In B.makeStr I am calling super.makeStr from class A, but in class C, I can't call super.super.makeStr from A, omitting class B. How to overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No you can't do that.

*All* classes in a heirarchy need to be constructed. You cannot *bypass* the construction of `B`.

What you *could* do is write a `protected` constructor in `B` that's essentially a no-op, and call that from the constructor in `C`.