# java inheritance misunderstanding

Tags: java, multiple-inheritance

The first question is inside the code. The second question is why static methods can't be overridden to be non-static methods? The third is why can't static and abstract go together?

```
class A {  
    public void display() {  
        System.out.println("Display of Class A called");  
    }  
}  

class B extends A {  
    public void display() {  
        System.out.println("Display of Class B called");  
    }  
}  

class C extends B {  
    public void display() {  
        System.out.println("Display of Class C called");  
        super.display(); // calls B's Display  
        // Is there a way to call A's display() from here? 
    }  
}
```

Comment: Think about what `static` means - it's not specific to any particular instance. Now think about how polymorphism works: the implementation used depends on the *instance* that a method is called on. See how they don't really work together? As for the other question, no, you can't. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/.

Comment: Additionally, please only ask *one question* at a time.

Answer (score 3):

> [B]  // Is there a way to call A's Display from here???[/B]

No, you can't go two steps up in the class hierarchy. You could implement and call a method in `B` which would invoke the `A` implementation.

> why `static` methods can't be overridden to be non-`static` methods

`static` methods are associated with a class. Polymorphism (and thus overriding) is a concept that applies to *objects* and therefore does not apply to them.

> why can't `static` and `abstract` go together

For the same reason given above. An `abstract` method is a method that should be implemented in a sub class because the sub class inherited it. Since a sub class does not inherit a `static` method, a `static` method cannot be `abstract`.

Answer (score 0):

First question: no you can't call the bass class's bass class directly, since in class C's view, it has no idea that class B has a bass class and it's class A. All that's know by C is that it has a base class, and it's B.

Second question: static methods are simply a neat way to organize global methods. There's no inheritance. You just put that method to a class so when you write code to call it, you know where to locate it.

Third question: `abstract` means "*this is what the class to do, here are some basic functionality, but I cannot finish this; inherit me and finish whatever is left to get it working*". As mentioned earlier, static method is just a way to put methods that "stand by themselves", requires no initialization and no context. The two does not go together.