# Class inheritance of java

Tags: java

I have 3 classes A B and C.

Class C  inherit from the B and B inherit from the A class

a -> b -> c

All of those classes have his own implement of `myMethod`

```
public void myMethod() {
    ...
}
```

How can I use the implementation of "MyMethod" of class A, into the class C?

Comment: You might find this relevant reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Comment: Smells like a design issue. Why would you want to do that?