# Casting the super variable to a class type

Tags: java

i have the following code :

```
class a {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("in a");
    }
}

class b extends a {
    void show() {
        System.out.println("in b");
    }
}

class c extends b {
    void show() {
        // can i do here
        ((a)super).show();
    }
}
```

kindly update if we can cast super variable to the superclass type.

b. why variables do not show the polymorphism phenomenon that overridden methods show.

c. i read that `super.super.methodname()` does not work removed to avoid violation of encapsulation.can anybody clarify on this how this is .

thanks

Comment: First of all super is not a variable. It's a keyword.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

> b. why variables do not show the polymorphism phenomenon that overridden methods show.

because field variables aren't polimorphic in java

> c. i read that super.super.methodname() does not workis removed to avoid violation of encapsulation.can anybody clarify on this how this is .

[because it isn't supported in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Comment: but i wanted to know how this violates encapsulation.kindly update on this.

Comment: @user Jon Skeet has given very good explanation on that post, summarizing it, you shouldn't be allowed to control directly on your super's super bypassing it

Comment: can super be cast to any class type

Comment: super refers to reference of parent type, for example in case of Animal and Human human's super would refer to Animal so you can cast super to any valid reference it can point to

Comment: why we are not able to cast super to class a .is it that java does not allow calling grandparent class methods from grandchildren class

Comment: _why we are not able to cast super to class a_ elaborate , answer to _a_ is already given