# How to call a method from within an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, bluej, method-call

I'm making a game with one of my friends. I am trying to call a method's return value to another method in the same class. I know how to do this under normal circumstances, but the class I'm using is abstract. I have looked over the internet for the answer, but I haven't found anything. This is the bit of code that I'm using:

```
public abstract class Game implements ActionListener 
{
   public static char KBoard(char w, char a, char s, char d) //This method takes in a keyboard command from the user, and returns that char.
{
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("");
      char kBoard = scan.next().charAt(0);
      return kBoard;
   }

   public static int MoveX (int velocity) 
{
      velocity = 5;//character moves this distance when a control key is pressed

      Game kBoard = new Game();//These lines here will
      kboard.KBoard();//call the KBoard method from above and the char it returns^^
      Switch ();
      {
        Case w:
        characterPosX -= velocity;//if the w key is pressed, character moves up
        break;

        Case s:
        characterPosX += velocity;//if the s key is pressed, character moves down
        break;
     }
    return characterPosX;//returns the new X position for the game character
  }
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calling non abstract method in abstract class java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27279341/calling-non-abstract-method-in-abstract-class-java)

Comment: When you post code, please post the *actual* code rather than pseudo-code. The code you've posted has various mistakes that would mean it doesn't compile - trivial ones that have nothing to do with that actual issue. Additionally, you've posted code but not said anything about what that does compared with what you want it to do. I'd also strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Abstract classes can't be used directly. You need to have an actual specialized class to use it. Then, as your methods are static, instead of using an instance of the specialized class, you just use the name of the base class, like this:

```
int x = SpecializedClassName.MoveX(1);
```

That can happen from anywhere, as static methods are always available.

Or, alternatively, you could simply use

```
int x = Game.MoveX(1);
```

Comment: Although, I need it to be a char, not an int. how would I do it for that?

Comment: You need MoveX() to return a char?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create `instance` of a `abstract class` and you don't need to `create` object to call `static` method. Instead do the following-

```
Game.KBoard();
```