# Super.super notation. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java

I have 3 classes. BankAccount, InterestAccount and IsaAccount.
InterestAccount extends BankAccount. IsaAccount extends InterestAccount.

This is what I have got for BankAccount for the withdraw method.

```
public void withdraw(int amount) {
    balance = balance - amount;
}
```

This is what I have got in InterestAccount for the withdraw method. (minimumBalance is the amount belof which balance should not fall but don't worry about it)

```
public void withdraw(int amount) {
    if (super.getBalance() - amount >= minimumBalance) {
        super.withdraw(amount);
    }
}
```

The question is what should I do to make a withdraw class for IsaAccount which kind of "extends twice"? I know super.super.balance isn't the case. What's the right way to do it?

Comment: This is what getBalance does:
    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

Comment: Why do you need to call `super.getBalance()` and "super.super.getBalance()"?  Is `getBalance()` inherited or overridden in the subclasses?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java