# Scala traits hierarchy doesn't compile

Tags: scala, inheritance, traits

In my venture to learning Scala, I created the following hierarchy:

```
trait Animal {
  val name: String = "Animal"
}

trait HasLegs {
  this: Animal =>
  val numLegs: Int
}

abstract class Terrestrial extends Animal with HasLegs {
  val name: String = "Terrestrial"
}

class Dog(val name: String) extends Terrestrial {
  def numLegs = 4

  override def toString = {
    f"My name is: $name%s. I'm a Dog and I've $numLegs%d legs. I'm from the ${super.name}%s family."
  }
}
```

However, the compiler complains that in `Dog.toString` "super may be not be used on value name". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a couple of issues, primarily stemming from using `val` in superclasses, which locks it down to a value, rather than something that can be overridden and accessed via `super`. There were also some problems with not specifying `override`:

```
trait Animal {
  // in order for super to be called on this it has to be a def
  def name: String = "Animal"
}

trait HasLegs {
  this: Animal =>
  val numLegs: Int
}

abstract class Terrestrial extends Animal with HasLegs {

  // this needs to be an override of Animal.name
  override def name: String = "Terrestrial"
}

class Dog(override val name: String) extends Terrestrial {

  // since the trait specified this as a val, the implementation
  // also needs to be a val
  val numLegs = 4

  override def toString = {
    f"My name is: $name%s. I'm a Dog and I've $numLegs%d legs. I'm from the ${super.name}%s family."
  }
}
```

I've commented on changes inline.

As for the reason why `super` cannot be used on `val` see [SI-899](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-899)

> This is the intended behavior, and it was changed so that traits could override vals to be more uniform with classes.

Comment: So here the name from Terrestrial will be invoked. Is there a way to get the name from the Animal? Or does super work for immediate superclass only?

Comment: See Jon Skeet's answer on why there is no super.super (he talks about Java but the same holds true for scala http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java