# Inheritance and super reference for Java

Tags: java, inheritance

Lets say I have a class called `Person`.
Then I make a child class called `Adult` (so an adult would `extend Person`)
Lastly, I make a child class of the `Adult` class called `Teacher` (so the `Teacher` would `extend Adult`)

If there was a `toString` method (`@Override`) for `Person` class, does all the child class (`Teacher` and `Adult`) have to have a `toString` method?

And if there is a `toString` method specific to `Person` and another `toString` specific to `Adult` class, how can I reference the `toString` method from the `Teacher` class from the `Adult` class using `super` reference? (all `toString`s are overridden)

Comment: having student extend teacher makes zero sense. it's saying all students are teachers.

Comment: *"does all the child class (teacher and Student) have to have a toString method?"* - `toString` is inherited from `Object`, so (technically speaking), they all have that method. If `Person` overrides `toString`, then when you call `Teacher#toString` or `Student#toString`, they will make use of `Person#toString`. You only need to override it if you wish to change what `Person#toString` changes

Comment: @cricket_007 *"so the Student would extend Person"* - I think it's typo/misunderstanding of the OP - one way or another, it's confusing

Comment: ["Is-a relationship"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) (in reference to what Nathan is saying)

Comment: Do I understand this correctly?  You want to write code in the `Adult` class that calls the `Teacher` class's version of `toString`?  If so, then this actually happens when you call `toString` if the object you're calling it on is a `Teacher`.  And if it isn't a `Teacher`, then it wouldn't make sense to call the `Teacher` class's method, since that method might reference methods (like `throwChalk`) that only exist in the `Teacher` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to simplify your question by renaming the classes A, B, and C.  B extends A.  C extends B.

For your first question: If A has a public `doSomething` method, then because of inheritance, B and C also have a doSomething method.  They don't have to declare or implement it, but they *may* if they wish to override the functionality and the method is not final.

For your second, you cannot reference the super of your super.  For instance, C could not call super.super.doSomething expecting to reference the doSomething in A, bypassing the doSomething in B.  By choosing to extend B, you take all the warts along with it, including whatever it chooses to do in its doSomething implementation.  If you need to reference A's doSomething from within C, then perhaps you extended the wrong class.  There are some great answers to that question here: [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Comment: Thank You so much! It helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

> If there was a toString method (override) for Person class, does all
>   the child class (teacher and Adult) have to have a toString method?

By the inheritance, all the subclasses(child) of Person automatically have a toString method, but return a string of Person (the parent) no the current class (the child).

if Employe extends Person, then you can call employe.toString() and will return the implemented on the Person class.