# how can access the age field of parent's parent in class C?

Tags: java, inheritance, extends

I teach some students.
How I can access A class's attribute age?

```
class A {
    protected int age;
    public A(int age){
        this.age = age+2;
    }
}
class B extends A{
    protected int age;
    public B(int age){
        super(age);
        this.age = age+1;
    }
}
class C extends B{
    protected int age;
    public C(int age){
        super(age);
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void showInfo(){
//      System.out.println(A.this.age);
        System.out.println(super.age);
        System.out.println(this.age);
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding `protected int age;` to the subclasses I think you are shadowing the super variable

Comment: `"I works for teaching some students."` -- ??

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've seen a very similar sentence in an advertisement for an English teacher.

Comment: Try to include `public void showInfo()` even in class B and in that you print `super.age` and then you call the function `super.showinfo()` in the overridden method in class C

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels better now? Doesn't make it into a good question, but it clears out that difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

It violates principles of object oriented design and is not possible in Java. There are some ugly workarounds, but if you're teaching students then it may be best to not even introduce this idea, or at least explain why it doesn't make sense.

This question is almost a duplicate if you really need a way of doing this: [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Comment: thanks nickburris. yes i know you mentioned already. i just wondered whether it can be accessed or not.

Answer (score 0):

With Following code , you can achieve.

```
class A{
    protected int age;
    public A(int age){
        this.age = age+2;
    }

    public void showInfo()
    {
        System.out.println("A : " +  this.age);
    }
}
class B extends A{
    protected int age;
    public B(int age){
        super(age);
        this.age = age+1;
    }

    public void showInfo()
    {
        super.showInfo();
        System.out.println("B : " +  this.age);
    }
}
class C extends B{
    protected int age;
    public C(int age)
    {
        super(age);
        this.age = age;
    }
    public void showInfo()
    {
        super.showInfo();
        System.out.println("C : " +  this.age);
    }
}
```