# How can i access Class A variable in m1() method directly?

Tags: java

```
class A {
    int i = 10;
}

class B extends A {
    int i = 20;
}

public class C extends B{
    int i = 30;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        C c = new C();
        c.m1();
    }

    public void m1() {
        System.out.println(i);       // 30
        System.out.println(super.i); // 20
    }
}
```

I have a class **A**, which contains a default variable. I created a child class **B** which extends class **A** and one more child class **C** which extends class **B**.

I want to access class **A** variable in child class **C** `m1()` method. Is there any direct way to access it?

Comment: ... why do all those variables have the same name? just give them different names. or, if you need the original value, don't change it

Comment: I seems like class A is your mother class so Why you don't extends class A on the class C ?

Comment: @FoxCy he does that, through extending B, wich extends A

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Comment: @Stultuske I know but in this part of exemple, the class C don't use any method of class B, that's why I suggest to directly use an extends of the A class in C.

Comment: @FoxCy I assume this code is a very minimalistic example to illustrate what he tries to do, not the complete code he's (trying to be) working with

Answer (score 6):

change this line

```
System.out.println(super.i); // 20
```

to

```
System.out.println(((A)this).i);
```

Answer (score 1):

To complicate your life try this:

```
public void m1() {
    System.out.println(this.i);
    C c = new C();
    Class<? extends Object> cls = c.getClass().getSuperclass().getSuperclass();
    Field[] fields = cls.getDeclaredFields();
    for ( Field field : fields )
    {
        String in = field.getName();
        int iv = field.get((Object)c);
        System.out.println(iv);
    }
}
```