# Access shadowed methods based on the casting type of the object

Tags: java, inheritance

Method calls are always determined based on the runtime type of the object, however how can I call shadowed methods of base classes from an inherit instance?

```
class Base {
    String str = "base";
    String str() { return str; }
}

class Impl extends Base {
    String str = "impl";
    String str() { return str; }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(((Base) new Impl()).str);   // print 'base'
        System.out.println(((Base) new Impl()).str()); // print 'impl'
    }
}
```

For example above, how can I call the `str()` method of `Base` class from an `Impl` instance, preferably without using reflection?

Comment: Methods aren't shadowed they are overridden. Only variables are shadowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using the Keyword super**

**Accessing Superclass Members**

If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword `super`. You can also use super to refer to a hidden field (although hiding fields is discouraged). an example below.

```
public class Superclass {

    public void printMethod() {
        System.out.println("Printed in Superclass.");
    }
}
```

calling printMethod since child class

Here is a subclass, called Subclass, that overrides printMethod():

```
public class Subclass extends Superclass {

    // overrides printMethod in Superclass
    public void printMethod() {
        super.printMethod();
        System.out.println("Printed in Subclass");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Subclass s = new Subclass();
        s.printMethod();    
    }
}
```

if you want to read more 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: This answer is correct, but I'm looking for `shadowed methods of base classes`. So is your anwser the only solution to get the method deep inside multi-layer base classes?

Comment: I don't think it's possible but why would you want to? Why you shouldn't do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/4248317

Comment: @Cyril It's not that I want to, but I'm currently writing a minijava interpreter, so I need to get the behaviours as close to java compiler as possible.

Comment: method execution calls work since down to up, starting since child-class to super-class, searching the specified method jumping between classes till to find and call it, 'super' just have only one level toward to parent. your situation would break the abstraction rules.