# How do I access Super class variables and methods in main method?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, name-hiding

```
    class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        C c = new C();

        c.show(); //how to access class A
    }

}

class A
{
    void show()
    {
    System.out.println("inside A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("inside B");
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    void show()
    {
        super.show(); //How to access class A
        System.out.println("inside C");
    }
}
```

Using **super** I can access *Super Class*  variables and methods like **C** can access **B**'s methods but what if I want to access **A**'s methods in **C**. How do I do that in simple way like using **super**? Like two super should do the trick... 
And how do I access Class A method only by allocating Class C(if name-hiding present)?

Comment: This is indicative of poor system design. Why is C extending B if C doesn't logically extend B? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Comment: Just trying to different situations...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no construct in Java to do something like `c.super.super.show()` as it violates encapsulation. [The Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) is a good principle illustrating why this is rightly avoided. Taking this into account, the way you can do what you request within Java is to expose `a.show()` in `b` like this:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        C c = new C();

        c.show(); //how to access class A
    }

}

class A
{
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("inside A");
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    void show()
    {
        System.out.println("inside B");
    }

    void showA()
    {
        super.show();
    }
}

class C extends B
{
    void show()
    {
        super.showA(); // Calls A
        System.out.println("inside C");
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, not possible in Java doing super.super.foo() or anything like that. You need to reach through direct parent.

Answer (score -1):

One way of using A's show() method in C is by creating class A object in C and using A's show function.

```
class C extends B
{
    void show()
    {
        new A().show();
        super.show();
        System.out.println("inside C");
    }
}
```

Comment: This assumes `show` is static, or at least can be treated as static.

Comment: `show` is not static , it is just creating temporary object and calling A's function

Comment: You're treating `show` as static by implying you can substitute a call to a different object's `show` in place of this object's. This is only a valid assumption if `show` does not rely on the individual object's properties, and thus can be treated as static.