# How to access similar fields of superclass in multilevel inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance

If base class and derived class have same field name, then we use super keyword to access base class field. But in case of multilevel inheritance and there also in every class has same field name, how to access field name of super class in child class.

```
class GrandParent {
  String name;
}

class Parent extends GrandParent {
  String name;
}

class Child extends Parent {
  String name;
  //now here, how to access GrandParent name field
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? (Also, that's not what the term "multiple inheritance" means.)

Comment: (1) You can't access the grandparent's fields from the child, if they've been overridden in the parent.  (2) This isn't multiple inheritance.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/586363) is similar.

Comment: Why can't comments be down-graded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no multiple inheritance here. Your snippet demonstrates *field hiding*.

Within a class, a field that has the same name as a field in the superclass hides the superclass's field, even if their types are different. Within the subclass, the field in the superclass cannot be referenced by its simple name. Instead, the field must be accessed through `super`.

`super` allows you to see members only on one level down (=members of the direct parent). Chains like `super.super` are considered syntactically invalid.

But there are at least two ways to achieve what you want:

1. `(GrandParent)this).name` - upcasting to `GrandParent`
2. `GrandParent.class.getDeclaredField("name").get(this)` - extraction by reflection