# Calling grandfather method

Tags: java

I'm writing a Java class that extends `AbstractList` because it has a lot of methods I want to inherit.

It has two methods I don't want to inherit: `equals` and `hashCode`. I would like to just call the default `Object` versions of those.

The syntax for calling an inherited method is e.g. `super.hashCode()` but that would just get the `AbstractList` version. What's the syntax for skipping over that and calling the grandfather version? `Object.hashCode()` doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is super.super.method(); not allowed in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a way to access grandfather method implementations.  On the other hand, you can use `System.identityHashCode(this)` and `this == o` to get the object-based equality behavior.

(Note, however, that it violates the `List` contract to use identity-based hash codes or equality for any type that implements the `List` interface.)