# Access hidden field from subclass of class that hides it

Tags: java, member-hiding

How can you access a `protected` field in a base class's base class that is hidden by a field in a base class?

An example:

```java
package foo;

public class Foo {
    protected int x;

    int getFooX() { return x; }
}
```

```java
package bar;

public class Bar extends foo.Foo {
    protected int x;

    // Can access foo.Foo#x through super.x
}
```

The `Foo` class's `x` field is shadowed by `Bar`'s field of the same name, but can be accessed by reflection:

```java
package baz;

public class Baz extends bar.Bar {
    {
        // Want getFooX() to return 2
        // ((foo.Foo) this).x = 2;  // Fails due to access error; Makes sense
        // super.x = 2;  // Changes bar.Bar#x
        // super.super.x = 2;  // Syntax error
        // foo.Foo.this.x = 2;  // Syntax error
        try {
            Field Foo_x = foo.Foo.class.getDeclaredField("x");
            Foo_x.setAccessible(true);
            Foo_x.setInt(this, 2);
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        // Doesn't compile error if field changes name
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without reflection, and without making changes to the superclasses?

Comment: The code in the question works, so what is the problem?

Comment: Per OP's comment in an answer below, he wanted a non-reflection solution.

Comment: @Rogue Then OP should say that *in the question*. Which is why I commented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes are in the same package, then you can cast `this` to the type you want to access the field of. Field names are resolved statically, based on the compile-time type of the expression on the left of the `.`, so the code below accesses `A`'s field because the expression `((A) this)` has compile-time type `A`.

```java
class A {
    protected int x = 1;
}

class B extends A {
    protected int x = 2;
}

class C extends B {
    int getAx() {
        return ((A) this).x;
    }

    void setAx(int x) {
        ((A) this).x = x;
    }
}
```

Note that this works only in the case where the classes are in the same package. In your example the classes are in different packages, so because the field is `protected` you'll get a compilation error.

In this case, it is impossible to access `A`'s field without reflection, because of this part of the Java Language Specification ([§6.6.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.2), emphasis mine):

> Let C be the class in which a protected member is declared. Access is permitted only within the body of a subclass S of C.
>
> In addition, if Id denotes an instance field or instance method, then:
>
> - ...
> - If the access is by a field access expression E.Id, or a method invocation expression E.Id(...), or a method reference expression E :: Id, where E is a Primary expression (§15.8), then **the access is permitted if and only if the type of E is S or a subclass of S**.

Here the class you're writing in is `C`, so the protected field of the superclass `A` is only accessible by an expression like `(expr).x` if the expression's type is `C` or a subclass of `C`. But in that case, the `.x` will always resolve to `B`'s field rather than `A`'s field.

Logically, it follows that accessing `A`'s field is not permitted by any field access expression in `C`.

We can also rule out the other kinds of expressions which can access a field: a [simple name](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5.6.1) `x` doesn't work, and a [super expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.11.2) cannot be chained like `super.super.x` (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java)).

Comment: Try putting `A`, `B`, and `C` in different packages (like the question has it), and see if it still works. It doesn't.

Comment: Oh, missed that. But this answer does work when they're in the same package. The question isn't worded specifically about the case where they're in different packages, although the example given does have them in different packages.

Comment: I've edited the answer to cover the case where they are in different packages. It turns out to be impossible without reflection, per the JLS.

Comment: *"it follows that accessing A's field is not permitted by **any** field access expression in C"*. Not true. C could access A's field if B hadn't hidden it.

Comment: ...the entire premise of the question is that B **has** hidden it, and that you can't change B to make it not hidden.

Comment: I know, but the sentence was too generic, and easy to misunderstand, hence I added clarifying *comment*.

Comment: It's not a generic statement; it is specifically about the classes `A`, `B` and `C` defined earlier within the answer. It refers to those classes by their names.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't work?

```
public static void main(String... args) {

        Baz b = new Baz();

        try {
            Field Foo_x = Foo.class.getDeclaredField("x");
            Foo_x.setAccessible(true);
            Foo_x.setInt(b, 2);
            System.out.println(b. getFooX());
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes that works but I was wondering if there was a not-using-reflection solution

Comment: I dont think so, encapsulation is a blocker here, or you have to modify the code