# I need clarity on specific condition on default method in interface in java

Tags: java, interface

I have a Query
Suppose I have a 2 interface f1 and f2 and f2 interface extends f1 interface.
both interface have default method m1 with some implementation.
now we have a class c1 which  implements f2 interface and we override m1() method.
now i can access f2 default method.
f2.super.m1().
how can i access f1 interface default method.
Please clarify me is it possible or not?

```
interface f1{
    public default void m1() {
        System.out.println("f1");
    };
}
interface f2 extends f1{
    public default void  m1(){
        System.out.println("f2");
    };
}
public class techgig implements f2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        techgig a = new techgig();
    a.m1();
    }
    @Override
    public void m1() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        f2.super.m1();
    }
}
```

It will print f2  but i want to print f1

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You can see the followong from java docs.

**Extending Interfaces That Contain Default Methods:**

> When you extend an interface that contains a default method, you can do the following:
>
> - Not mention the default method at all, which lets your extended interface inherit the default method.
> - Redeclare the default method, which makes it abstract.
> - Redefine the default method, which overrides it.

from the documentation we can see when we extends an interface that has a default method. If we redefine the default method, it will override the default method. In your case interface `f1` default method is overridden by implementation in `f2` interface.

If you want to get the output of default method in interface `f1` don't redefine the default method in interface `f2`.

If you change your interface `f2` as below you will get the output "f1".

```
interface f2 extends f1 {
    
}
```

Reference: [Default Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html)