# How can I access the superclass toString method?

Tags: java, inheritance, superclass

```
public class override {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c1 obj = new c1();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class a1 {
    public String toString (){
        return "this is clas a";
    }
}

class b1 extends a1{
    public String toString (){
        return "this is clas b";
    }
}

class c1 extends b1{
    public String toString (){
        return super.toString() + "\nthis is clas c";
    }
    
}
```

I need to access the superclass `a1` `toString` method in `c1` subclass. Is there any way to do it. I'm learning java, any help would be a great support.

Comment: it is not posible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably like to have something as `super.super.toString()`. But this is not allowed in java. So you can simply use it twice as bellow :

```
public class override {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        c1 obj = new c1();
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}

class a1 {
    public String toString (){
        return "this is clas a";
    }
}

class b1 extends a1{
    public String toString (){
        return "this is clas b";
    }

    public String superToString(){
        return super.toString();
    }
}

class c1 extends b1{
    public String toString (){
        return super.superToString() + "\nthis is clas c";
    }
}
```

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586363/why-is-super-super-method-not-allowed-in-java?lq=1) may also help.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can't - you can't access "grandparent" directly, only via the parent if it allows you to do that.

Class `b1` has a `toString` definition that doesn't call `super.toString` so its class `b1` that has decided to "override" the functionality of the grandparent's (a1) `toString` method. Since class `c1` extends `b1` - you "see" only this overridden version and not the version of `toString` of `a1`.

Now practically if you need this piece of functionality (lets pretends that its not toString but some code that can be required from all the children, you can do the following:

```
class a1 {
    protected String commonReusableMethod() {
        return "this is clas a";
    }
    public String toString (){
        return commonReusableMethod();
    }
}

class b1 extends a1{
    public String toString (){
        return "this is clas b";
    }
}

class c1 extends b1{
    public String toString (){
        return super.toString() + "\nthis is clas c" + "\n" +
        commonReusableMethod(); // you can call this method from here
    }
    
}
```

Note the definition of `commonReusableMethod` - it is `protected` so you can call it from anywhere in the hierarchy (from `a1`, `b1`, `c1`)

If you don't want to allow overriding this protected method, add also `final`:

```
protected final commonReusableMethod() {...}
```

Comment: The call to `commonReusableMethod()` apparently isn't reachable.

Comment: @MartinZeitler - what do you mean? There was a small typo around `\n` - I've fixed that, other than that - this code should run (I've verified with Java 8 installation)