# How do I call a parent parent class method from a child class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I've been checking out the Kotlin [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html#overriding-rules) about inheritance, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
open class A {
    open fun f() {
        println("A::f()")
    }
}

open class B : A() {
    override fun f() {
        println("B::f()")
    }
}

class C : B() {
    override fun f() {
        // How can i call A.f() in here
        println("C::f()")
    }
}

fun main() {
    val c = C()
    c.f()
}
```

In the `C` class, which is a subclass of `B`, I want to call the `f()` method of the `A` class from `f()` of `C` class. In languages like C++, I could achieve this using `A::f()`, but I'm unsure of the Kotlin equivalent. Can someone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot call `super<A>.f()` because `C` is not an immediate supertype ~ https://pl.kotl.in/77cXiZKJA

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/586397/5133585). This is not possible in Kotlin, and you should not do this in the first place.