# object-reference as string?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

In java, you can get a [unique string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-ha) for an object.

How can you do this in as3?

Comment: Just to be clear, Java's hashCode() isn't exactly "unique"... hash collisions can still cause distinct objects to return the same hashCode() value.

Comment: this is a helpful page ( http://www.morearty.com/blog/2008/07/28/actionscripts-different-ways-to-convert-an-object-to-a-string/ ), but the results are not unique...  in fact, most are exactly the same for a given type of object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the same vain as the responses on the java thread, the is a unique ID generator as part of the flex SDK. This is found under mx.utils.UIDUtil, it works fairly simply.

```
var ID:String  = UIDUtil.createUID();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also in flex, there is createUniqueName in mx.utils.NameUtil

Answer (score 4):

you can use this, to get a unique uint ... if you want to, convert it to a string ... :-P

```
package {
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;
    public class ObjectUIDUtil {
        private static var _uids:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
        private static var _cter:uint = 1;
        public static function getUID(obj:Object):uint {
            var ret:uint = _uids[obj];
            return (ret == 0) ? (_uids[obj] = _cter++) : ret;
        }
    }
}
```

please note, that this maybe is not even necessary, since `flash.utils.Dictionary` allows using objects as keys directly ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: I'm curious, what's the advantage of using `Dictionary` over a normal Object? (I honestly don't know and am interested).

Comment: The problem here is, that if you use any value as a key for an `Object` the value is converted to a string and objects of the same type have the same string representation by default, so you'd get the same id for every instance of the same class. `Dictionary` leaves the value largely unmodified, although it will treat the `String` `"1"` and the `int` `1` as the same key, but it will distinguish non-primitive objects by their identity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a third party hashing function (such as md5 or sha1). The hashcode for objects in Java (incidentally C#) is generated by a hashing function as well. [Here's one I found on Google](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/)

Hope this helps.