# How to print out an object memory address at runtime? like this.toString() in java

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, object, tostring, memory-address

How to write an AS3 object's memory location for example to a label?
I need it for debugging purposed. Thanx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long answer: you can do it but it's a dirty, dirty hack: [How can I get an instance's "memory location" in ActionScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343282/how-can-i-get-an-instances-memory-location-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 1):

NameUtil.createUniqueName() is pretty handy for this type of thing.

Comment: Or a uuid as well using  mx.utils.UIDUtil.createUID()

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: there is no way to do that.
However, you can search something in flash.sampler package.

Comment: This is incorrect. It is possible, just a hack: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343282/how-can-i-get-an-instances-memory-location-in-actionscript