# Get object identity in ActionScript 3

Tags: actionscript-3

For debugging purposes I'd like to trace the internal ID of some objects. You know, the stuff you get in error reports sometimes, `SuperObject@a8D7a2`

Is this possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get an instance's "memory location" in ActionScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343282/how-can-i-get-an-instances-memory-location-in-actionscript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such.

Would [creating a unique ID on demand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151627/object-reference-as-string/1153833#1153833) do the trick?

Comment: That would work, though in this case I've solved it by using the debugger in Flex Builder.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that was sufficient for my needs is simpler still, Create an instance variable holding a random number. This is likely (but not guaranteed) to be different for each object, depending how many you have.

```
    private var _id:int = Math.random() * 10000000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myObject.name = "Id_"+x;
```

... or something else dynamic string;

If You don't want add an Id, just see during the debug process, just trace it.

```
trace(myObject.name );
```

Air decompiler add an unique name to every display object.
(like this: Instance105 )