# Why are these variables not loading in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I cannot find whats wrong with this code.  I have short type array called "data". I assign data[i] value to private Point objects variable x then I add this object to ArrayList and proceed with next i.  In the arraylist all instances have same value - last one that was added. Why do you think its so?

```
    ArrayList<Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();

        System.out.println("start test");
    for (int i=0;i<data.length;i++){

        bPunkt.x=(int) data[i];
        p.add(bPunkt);
        System.out.println(""+bPunkt.x);
    }
        System.out.println("middle of test");
    for (int i=0;i<p.size();i++){
        System.out.println(""+p.get(i).x);
    }
        System.out.println("end test");
```

this is what system.out prints :

```
start test
1
0
1
3
3
5
3
5
5
4
middle of test
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
4
end test
```

Comment: You need to assign a new instance to `bPunkt` before adding.

Answer (score 2):

You are modifying the same instance `bPunkt` and sticking it in the list. So in the end you have a list with the same object over and over in it.

Comment: Next time you feel stuck with such issues, print object references. It really helps.

Comment: You can only do that if you do __not__ override `toString()`.

Comment: Actually I stand [corrected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-h).