# Java String references

Tags: java, string, reference

When I run the following code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(args[0]);
        System.out.println("testing");
        System.out.println(args[0] == "testing");
    }
}
```

using

> java Test testing

at the command line, it prints the following:

testing
testing
false

My understanding is that, when comparing Strings, == compares the references of the Strings, not their values. For the two Strings in the following code, how can I find out what their references are?

```
System.out.println(args[0] == "testing");
```

Comment: Side question: why do you care? Rule of thumb: unless you really know what you are doing, always use .equals()

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: It's not a duplicate of that particular question - see his question at the end. One way to see the reference values is in a debugger.

Comment: Do you want to find the value of the references themselves in a debugger or in code? The latter has been addressed in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-h/581020#581020 .

Comment: Thanks all. I was just curious whether it could be done (simply), so that I could see what was being compared. Thanks for the links.

Comment: references are pretty much useless in themselves. == and .equals are useful - a reference tells you virtually nothing in itself unless you're profiling the internals of the heap... and even then it may not be that useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `equals()`, `compareTo()`, `equalsIgnoreCase()` when comparing `Strings`.

You only need references if you want to do something with memory locations which I am not sure why you would want to do.

That defeats the purpose of Java and you should switch to C if that is what you are looking for or if you want to perform actions on memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that, when comparing Strings, == compares the references of the Strings, not their values

Indeed; but then replace `String` with `Object` in the sentence above, or indeed *any class implementing `Object`* (which means, in essence, each and every Java class) and the above sentence will hold...

Except that "values" is too vague.

There is a fundamental contract in Java, and that is `Object`'s `.equals()` and `.hashCode()`. They are intrinsically linked to one another. What they essentially define is an equivalence contract.

The base equivalence contract for `Object` is simple, really; given two `Object`s `o1` and `o2`, it is true that:

```
o1.equals(o2)
```

is strictly equivalent to:

```
o1 == o2
```

But it is only because for `Object`, `.equals()` is defined as such:

```
// pseudo code...
public boolean equals(final Object o)
{
    returns this == o;
}
```

Now, of course, this won't stand true for `String`. A `String` has state (its characters), an `Object` doesn't. Therefore `String` "refines" `.equals()`. Which means that even if you have:

```
String s1 = "hello world";
String s2 = "hello world";
```

it is **not true** that:

```
s1 == s2
```

(save for particular, irrelevant scenarios), but it **is** true that:

```
s1.equals(s2)
```

As a "side effect", this also means that `String` also has to "refine" `.hashCode()` as well, since the contract explicitly stipulates that two objects which are `equals()` must have the same `hashCode()`.