# Java8: Hashmap overriden tostring behaviour

Tags: java, java-8

I have a hash map in java 8. I want to print reference of hash map instead of its content. In java 8 when I print hash map using its to String method it prints content. How can I get object reference printed?

```
Map<String,String> m = new HashMap<String,String>();
m.put("abc","def");
System.out.println("m is"+m); //need to get object reference not content
```

Comment: What do you mean by "object reference" printed?

Comment: It may give you the idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/580984/how-do-you-get-the-object-reference-of-an-object-in-java-when-tostring-and-h

Comment: Who gave you the idea that the default Object.toString() had anything to do with an "object reference"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this to get what the Object.toString method would return:

```
String s = m.getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(m.hashCode());
System.out.println(s);
```