# If Strings in java are immutable, why I can do this?

Tags: java

I realize that the hashCode of the variable name, is different after the "update", but objectively what makes a String object in fact immutable ?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str = "AB";
         System.out.println(str ); // AB

         str = str .replace(str .charAt(0) ,'W');
         System.out.println(str );//WB

 }
```

EDIT 1 : The hashCode is based on the value of the variable and have no relation with memory adress.

EDIT 2 : I now understand that Strings are references and not Objects in it self.
I read back all the answers for this same question and found out good answers in topics like [this] ([Immutability of Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552301/immutability-of-strings-in-java)). Thank you whos tried to help me and my excuses for any silly misunderstood.

I also recommend this articles here to who wants better understand how Strings works in Java :

https://www.pushkarrajpujari.com/article/strings-in-java/

and how references works :

https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

EDIT 3: I cannot DELETE this topic anymore, according with Stackoverflow "You cannot delete this question as others have invested time and effort into answering it." which I agree.

Comment: The string returned from replace is a different string. The variable is not the object. You just overwrite the reference to one string with a reference to another string.

Comment: You're not mutating the String.  You're assigning a **new** String to the same variable.

Comment: Variables are always mutable, in the sense that they can be made to reference new objects,  even when the objects themselves are immutable.

Comment: Variables are variable (duh).

Comment: BTW that is not the address of the variable, but the address of the object the variable is pointing to (or the content of the variable (since it is a reference/pointer)) ((haven't checked the documentation, but doubt that is not explained))

Comment: `addressOf(str)` does not give you the address of the variable `str`, but instead the address of the object it is referencing. Keep in mind that `31864662320` == `0x76b482930`.

Comment: @Progman, thanks for your answer man. I already erase my misguided edit.

Comment: @Progman, thanks for your answer man. I already erase my misguided edit.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn Well, there are also *constant variables*, like ones marked `static final`.

Comment: @Progman Well, it's not a memory address per se. It is implementation specific, and *appears* to be a memory address or a part of it. See [here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1961146/memory-address-of-variables-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation of `replace()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)), it mentions:

> Returns a new string resulting from replacing all occurrences of oldChar in this string with newChar.

Therefore, the replaced String is an entirely new String.

Comment: You are right man, my bad don´t look at documentation first.

Comment: But, I know that hashCode does not represent the memory adress of the variable, so how can I check or CONFIRM the immutability of a String ?

Comment: @RaphaelSilva [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/580987/1898437) (and perhaps other answers for the same question) may be of help.

Comment: Hey @Anoop, thanks for your answer. Before close this topic, I did my research I´d like to answer my own question here for the posterity.

Comment: @RaphaelSilva Sure, go ahead!